# clear input fields after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to clear input fields after I submit a form but it only clear text but i need that border and some attributes will be too

//validation name

```
document.questionform.name.onchange= function() {
            var name = document.questionform.name.value;
            if (name === "") {
                document.questionform.name.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
                document.questionform.name.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                document.getElementById("questionError").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("questionErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                    document.questionform.name.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                    document.getElementById("questionError").style.display = "none";
                    var pattern = new RegExp("^[а-я]+$", "i");
                    var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;
                    if (!(isValid)) {
                        document.questionform.name.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                        document.getElementById("questionErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
                        document.questionform.name.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("questionErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                        document.questionform.name.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                        document.questionform.name.setAttribute("class", "ready");
                    }
            }
        };
```

Ajax:
      $("#questionsave").click(function() {

```
    var url = "questionForm.php"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#questform").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
                var name = $('input[name=name]').val("");
                var tel = $('input[name=phone]').val("");
                document.questionform.phone.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
                document.questionform.name.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
                document.getElementById("questionsave").setAttribute("disabled");
                document.getElementById("questionsave").style.cursor = "not-allowed";
                document.getElementById("questionsave").style.opacity = "0.8";
                document.questionform.name.style.borderColor = "#e4e4e6";
                document.questionform.phone.style.borderColor = "#e4e4e6";
           }
         });

    return false; 
    });
```

Comment: reload page?after submit?

Comment: yes after submit, in my code it clears only text

Comment: higlight these somehow which exactly execpt text you say is not removed in case this issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying. After form submit the form is already reset. It retains its value when you are using ajax. In that case try this:

```
$('#form_id')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` for your `form` and use this,

```
document.getElementById("formId").reset();
```